# In R, how can I set the names of an object and return it in one line?

Tags: r, names

I would like to set the names of my R object and return it in one line. It should look something like:

```
names(doWork(), c("a", "b", "c"))
```

And perform the equivalent of:

```
x <- doWork()

names(x) <- c("a", "b", "c")

x
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This gives the answer to that, but that does not give the answer to this. This is more general than numeric vectors.

Comment: Wouldn't `setNames` work on the `doWork()`?

Comment: `\`names<-\`(x, c('a','b','c'))` if you want people to think you're cool

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try `setNames`

```
x <- setNames(doWork(), letters[1:3])
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to what @rawr states:

```
`names<-`(x, letters[1:3])
```

works.  This isn't super interesting for setting names, since `setNames` exists, but there are many other attribute replacement functions that don't have a corresponding attribute setting function, so this can become useful (when playing code golf).  For example, if we want to set column names for a list of matrices:

```
mats <- replicate(2, matrix(sample(1:100, 4), 2), simplify=F) # list of matrices
lapply(mats, `colnames<-`, LETTERS[1:2])
```

Produces:

```
[[1]]
      A  B
[1,] 78 59
[2,] 39 93

[[2]]
      A  B
[1,] 99 54
[2,]  1 16
```

Comment: Just a nitpicky point: If you're code golfing in R, `setNames()` is shorter than `\`names<-\`()`. ;)

Comment: @AlexA., I'm referring to those cases where there isn't a `setX` attribute setting function available.

Comment: I know, I just mean in that particular case for code golf. That's completely an aside; this is a good answer. +1

Comment: @AlexA., np, figured the +1 was from you, just clarifying for the record